# Unable to query from database using JPA in custom repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am getting this error whenI lauch

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in xxxxxxx.Repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract xxxxx.Model.User xxxxx.Repository.UserRepository.findByEmail(java.lang.String)! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract xxxx.Model.User xxxxx.Repository.UserRepository.findByEmail(java.lang.String)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract xxxx.Model.User xxxxx.Repository.UserRepository.findByEmail(java.lang.String)
```

This is m repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

     @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = ?1")
     public User findByMail(String mail);
}
```

Whe is rong here?

Comment: You don't need the `@Query` assuming the field is named `mail` else rewrite your method to `findByEMail`. Please add the full-stracktrace as well as your `User` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
     public User findByMail(@Param("mail") String mail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email =:mail",nativeQuery=true)
 public User findByMail(String mail);
```